# How to limit protected member to be accessible from only first level child C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have 3 level classes.

- `TopClass`
- `MiddleClass`
- `BottomClass`

And `MiddleClass` is derived from `TopClass` and `BottomClass` is derived from `MiddleClass`.

I want to have a property in `TopClass` which could only be accessible from `TopClass` and `MiddleClass` not the `BottomClass`.

As I am using `protected` access modifier, the protected property in `TopClass` is accessible from `BottomClass`.

Here are my classes to give better insight.

```
public class TopClass
 {
    private string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass { get; set; } 
    protected string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass { get; set; } // I want this to be accessible only by the MiddleClass 
    public string AccessibleFromEverywhere { get; set; } // this is good as it is public so accessible everywhere

    public virtual void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
       ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass = "I can access this here as it is grand father's private member!"; 
    }
 }


 public class MiddleClass : TopClass
 {
     public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
     {
         base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "As this is a MiddleClass class, I am accessible here.. That is good!";
     }
 }


 public class BottomClass : MiddleClass
 {
     public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
     {
         base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "I don't want this to be accessible here!";
     }
 }
```

I want `ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass`  to be only accessible from the `MiddleClass` and `TopClass`, not from `BottomClass`.

How can I do that? And as I cannot do this with existing access modifiers such as `protected`, `public`, `internal` , `private` etc..  is it a sign that I am trying to break some sort of rule here?

Comment: Have you tried `seal` keyword?

Comment: That's generally not possible in C#. There might be other options depending on what you're trying to achieve, but it's hard to tell with the abstract design you're showing us here.

Comment: @TấnNguyên -  if you use *sealed* class than you can no more inherit from that. In this case, I cannot use *BottomClass* to be inherited. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you want only `MiddleClass`, specifically, to be able to access the member, or do you want *any* direct subclass of `TopClass` to be able to access it? E.g. if I were to make `class AnotherMiddleClass : TopClass`, should it be able to access the member?

Comment: @JoeSewell - for what I am trying to solve right now, it really does not matter for me. So if you know anyway like a workaroud I would love to hear it.. thanks

Comment: @AnoopRDesai - that post and its answers are 5 years old. A lot change in .net framework since then

Comment: @curiousBoy My concept here we could work-very-around by giving `ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass ` private in `TopClass` and only call it from `proctected virtual OnlyMiddleClass()`. Then in `MiddleClass` we could only call, access from `base.OnlyMiddleClass()` and override that as `protected override sealed string OnlyMiddleClass() => null;` to restrict the `Bottom` could access that destination variable. [My gist here](https://gist.github.com/zhenyuan0502/698245e67fa93e43a9b7e0579624d1ba)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a *specific* `MiddleClass` that should have privileged access to a member of `TopClass`, you can put `MiddleClass` in `TopClass` as a nested type. Nested types have access to all members of their enclosing type.

```
public class TopClass
{
    private string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass { get; set; } 
    private string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass { get; set; } // I want this to be accessible only by the MiddleClass 
    public string AccessibleFromEverywhere { get; set; } // this is good as it is public so accessible everywhere

    public virtual void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
        ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass = "I can access this here as it is grand father's private member!"; 
    }

    public class MiddleClass : TopClass
    {
        public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
        {
            base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "As this is a MiddleClass class, I am accessible here.. That is good!";
        }
    }

}

public class BottomClass : TopClass.MiddleClass
{
    public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
        // compilation error:
        // base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "I don't want this to be accessible here!";
    }
}
```

If you have one or more `MiddleClass` classes in the same assembly as `TopClass`, and all the `BottomClass` classes are going to be in another assembly, you can use `private protected`. It means "access to only classes that are BOTH `internal` and `protected`", whereas `protected internal` means "access to classes that are EITHER `internal` or `protected`".

```
// in Assembly A

public class TopClass
{
    private string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass { get; set; } 
    private protected string ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass { get; set; } // I want this to be accessible only by the MiddleClass 
    public string AccessibleFromEverywhere { get; set; } // this is good as it is public so accessible everywhere

    public virtual void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
        ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClass = "I can access this here as it is grand father's private member!"; 
    }
}

public class MiddleClass : TopClass
{
    public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
        base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "As this is a MiddleClass class, I am accessible here.. That is good!";
    }
}

// in Assembly B, which references Assembly A

public class BottomClass : MiddleClass
{
    public override void SomeWeirdFunction()
    {
        // compile error
        // base.ThisIsOnlyAccessibleForTopClassAndMiddleClass = "I don't want this to be accessible here!";
    }
}
```