# Preventing access to base method from derived class

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Given the following classes structure, is there a way to prevent `BaseMethod()` from being called or seen from `FinalClass`?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void BaseMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class IntermediateClass : BaseClass
{
    protected sealed override void BaseMethod()
    {
        base.BaseMethod();
    }

    private void IntermediateMethod()
    {
        BaseMethod();
    }
}

public class FinalClass : IntermediateClass
{
    protected void FinalMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106341/how-to-limit-protected-member-to-be-accessible-from-only-first-level-child-c-sha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `BaseMethod` `internal` and place `FinalClass` in a different assembly to `BaseClass` and `IntermediateClass`.